# Erro PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php

Eu preciso fazer uma validação, se for verdadeiro vai para um link e se for falso vai para outro lugar.
meu código é seguinte.

```
<a href='<?php if($dado['st_nome'] =="FINALIZADO")
{echo "dashboard.php?link=17&id=<?php echo $dado["op_id"];?>";}
else{ echo '#';}?>'>
```

Mas está me retornando o

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in E:\home\gigaclima\Web\giga_proj\paginas\listas\listar_op.php on line 50`

Algo no código está gerando um conflito que não consigo identificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma vez que já estás no PHP não precisas abrir novamente, entendes?

O correto seria assim:

```
<a href='<?php if($dado['st_nome'] =="FINALIZADO")
{echo "dashboard.php?link=17&id={$dado['op_id']}";}
else{ echo '#';} ?>'>
```

Mas eu aconselhava-te a fazer assim:

```
<?php
if( $dado['st_nome'] == "FINALIZADO" )
    $link = "dashboard.php?link=17&id=".$dado["op_id"];
else 
    $link= "#";
?>
<a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'>
```

Para ter o mínimo de PHP no meio do HTML. Fica menos confuso.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que ainda pode utilizar um ternário como opção:

```
<?php
     $dado['st_nome'] == "FINALIZADO" ?  $link = "dashboard.php?link=17&id=".$dado["op_id"]: $link= "#"; 
?>

<a href='<?php echo $link; ?>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código estava escrito errado, segue a correção do mesmo, sem alteração no seu estilo:

```
<a href='<?php
    if($dado['st_nome'] =="FINALIZADO"){
        echo "dashboard.php?link=17&id=" .  $dado["op_id"]; 
    }else{ 
        echo '#';        
    } ?>'>Link</a>
```

Também tem a versão postada por Jorge B., que separa o PHP do HTML e deixa o código mais limpo.